# Error: Could not find or load main class CrossBrowserTesting.ChromeTesting

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   CrossBrowserTesting.ChromeTesting Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CrossBrowserTesting.ChromeTesting

From the following code, can you sort it out?

```
package CrossBrowserTesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class ChromeTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\selenium webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)